# Sequential nested list with string concatenation

Tags: python, list

Given the nested list:

```
l = [['a','b','c'], ['d'], ['e','f']]
```

I would like to join them sequentially with `'/'.join()`.

With the expected `list` result:

```
['a/d/e', 'a/d/f', 'b/d/e', 'b/d/f', 'c/d/e', 'c/d/f']
```

The solution needs to be able to scale (2D list of various sizes).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like permutations check the `itertools` library I think.

Comment: I've tried looking at `itertools` - `product`, `permutations`, `combinations`; I still can't figure out how to apply them to a nested structure, where order matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's known as a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Here's an approach using `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools as it
list("/".join(p) for p in it.product(*l))
```

Output:

```py
['a/d/e', 'a/d/f', 'b/d/e', 'b/d/f', 'c/d/e', 'c/d/f']
```

The `itertools.product` function takes an arbitrary number of iterables as arguments (and an optional `repeat` parameter). What I'm doing with `*l` is unpacking your sublists as separate arguments to the `itertools.product` function. This is essentially what it sees:

```py
it.product(["a", "b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"])
```

PS - you could actually use strings as well, since strings are iterable:

```py
In [6]: list(it.product("abc", "d", "ef"))
Out[6]:
[('a', 'd', 'e'),
 ('a', 'd', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd', 'e'),
 ('b', 'd', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd', 'f')]
```

Beware that the size of the Cartesian product of collections `A`, `B`, etc is the product of the sizes of each collection. For example, the Cartesian product of `(0, 1)`, `("a", "b", "c")` would be 2x3=6. Adding a third collection, `(5, 6, 7, 8)` bumps the size up to 24.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the sublists and use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
out = ['/'.join(tpl) for tpl in product(*l)]
```

Output:

```
['a/d/e', 'a/d/f', 'b/d/e', 'b/d/f', 'c/d/e', 'c/d/f']
```